# How can I remove plot markers at some desired points?

Tags: plotting, graphics, marker

How can I remove plot markers at some data points? 
For example, I want to remove one plot marker at the circled point leaving only one marker there. 
 I tried deleting the data points but this would also delete part of the lines which is not wanted. 
It would be good if I can input the data points where the markers should be removed. Assume that I already know the coordinate (data points) of these to be removed markers.

[image]

```
    (*Load the package code*)
    package = 
      Import["http://raw.github.com/AlexeyPopkov/PolygonPlotMarkers/\
    master/PolygonPlotMarkers.m", "Text"];
    
    (*Install the package (existing file will be overwritten!)*)
    Export[FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", 
        "PolygonPlotMarkers.m"}], package, "Text"];
    Needs["PolygonPlotMarkers`"]

    data = {Table[{x, 1 + 2 x}, {x, 0, 5, 1}], 
       Table[{x, 1 + x}, {x, 0, 5, 1}]} ;
    markers = {"Circle", "ThreePointedStar"};
    colors = {Blue, Red};
    Graphics[Table[{colors[[i]], Line[data[[i]]], FaceForm[White], 
       EdgeForm[{colors[[i]], AbsoluteThickness[2], JoinForm["Miter"]}], 
       PolygonMarker[markers[[i]], Offset[7], data[[i]]]}, {i, 
       Length[data]}], AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 450, 
     Frame -> True]


My orginal problem:
```

I want to remove markers at these points keeping only one markers there.
[image]

```
(*Load the package code*)
package = 
  Import["http://raw.github.com/AlexeyPopkov/PolygonPlotMarkers/\
master/PolygonPlotMarkers.m", "Text"];
    
    (*Install the package (existing file will be overwritten!)*)
    Export[FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", 
        "PolygonPlotMarkers.m"}], package, "Text"];
    Needs["PolygonPlotMarkers`"]
    
    data = Table[{x, BesselJ[k, x]}, {k, 0, 4}, {x, 0, 10, 0.5}];
    markers = {"Circle", "ThreePointedStar", "FourPointedStar", 
       "FivePointedStar", "Circle"};
    colors = {Blue, Red, Darker@Green, Darker@Yellow, Orange};
    Graphics[Table[{colors[[i]], Line[data[[i]]], FaceForm[White], 
       EdgeForm[{colors[[i]], AbsoluteThickness[1], JoinForm["Miter"]}], 
       PolygonMarker[markers[[i]], Offset[7], data[[i]]]}, {i, 
       Length[data]}], AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 450, 
     Frame -> True]
```

Comment: Have you Tried ListPlot!?
it's easier to work with PolygonMarker

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PolygonMarker

Comment: @Alrubaie not yet, would it work if I want to remove some markers?

Comment: it's better and easier handling PolygonMarker inside ListPlot function.

                              Check the link!!!
part:
Create a tuned up Graphics marker in one step:

In[4]:= mtps = ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"][
  "ThreePointedStar", {Offset[7], 0}, {EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[None]}]

Comment: @Alrubaie I read that link before and my code above is basically from there. But my main goal is to remove markers at some specific points.

Comment: @Alrubaie I think you misunderstood my question. I want to remove markers at some points instead of changing to a different marker's types.

Comment: Humble request:  Ask the *simplest* (minimal) version of your question.  You can get to the core idea with a *single* plot with three points, one of which you'd like to eliminate.  No need for loading packages of colors;  no need for Bessel functions;  no need for setting AspectRatio, or ImageSize, or EdgeForm, or Frame, or ...  You'll get lots more help.  AND you are more likely to find your answer on your own.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork thanks for the advice. I made a new one with simpler code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = {Table[{x, 1 + 2 x}, {x, 0, 5, 1}], 
   Table[{x, 1 + x}, {x, 0, 5, 1}]};

colors = {Blue, Red};

markers = MapThread[
 First @ ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"][#, {Offset[7], 0}, {EdgeForm[#2], FaceForm[White]}]&,
 {{"Circle", "ThreePointedStar"}, colors}];

Graphics[Table[{colors[[i]], Line[data[[i]]], FaceForm[White], 
   EdgeForm[{colors[[i]], AbsoluteThickness[2], JoinForm["Miter"]}], 
   Translate[markers[[i]], #] & /@ If[i == 1, data[[i]], Rest[data[[i]]]]}, 
  {i, Length[data]}], 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 450, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I got this error ```Syntax::sntxb: Expression cannot begin with "[PolygonMarker][#,{Offset[7],0},{EdgeForm[#2],FaceForm[White]}]".```

Comment: What would I modify if there is more than 2 overlapping markers at one place and in some places?

Comment: The markers is giving me errors but I don't know what should it be like to modify it.

Comment: I updated my question with my original problem which is a bit more complex.

Comment: @kglr I've edited the answer to add what I think was a missing call to `ResourceFunction` that was causing the syntax error. Feel free to revert if I've misinterpreted.

Comment: Thank you so much @MarcoB.